# Bypass the messages - Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have written the batch file  as below :

```
D:\Build\Build_2.0.023\GrConv\FTGraphicConverter.exe -s "D:\Customer Data\JSM Prj\JSM_DEMO\HIS0364\WINDOW\L3_TB3B_MNFLD.EDF" -d "D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common" -l "D:\FastTools\VPInput\CentumTagsToFASTTOOLSitems.csv"


D:\Build\Build_2.0.023\GrConv\FTGraphicConverter.exe -s "D:\Customer Data\JSM Prj\JSM_DEMO\HIS0364\WINDOW\L3_TB3B_MNFLD.EDF" -d "D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common" -l "D:\FastTools\VPInput\CentumTagsToFASTTOOLSitems.csv"



xcopy D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common\Displays C:\Users\Public\tls\wap\cfg\operatorInterfaces\DEPLOY\displays /y
```

when i am running it and due to some reason the 1st line fails then it shows the error message on command windows and does not move the 2nd line of execution  without manual intervention.

I want to suppress the error message and move to second line of execution automatically .

Comment: FTGraphicConverter.exe is generating the error message and stopping the execution.

What kind of error is it?  Missing files?

Comment: The message is :error occured during the conversion! please check the logfile.

Comment: One solution would be to use a different converter or look at the documentation to see if it has an option to run without prompting.

Comment: do you mean "FTGraphicConverter.exe " may havwe the option to run as without throwing the messages.  any other  solution at batch file level..

Comment: I can't find it on google to see.  You can use Autoit perhaps - either to press space or whatever every so often (the key needed to continue after the error) - someone in their forums might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Start /B to don't stop the execution of your script when launching a process, that means all process starting with "/B" will start at once:

```
Start /B Process.exe

Start /B "" "D:\Build\Build_2.0.023\GrConv\FTGraphicConverter.exe" -s "D:\Customer Data\JSM Prj\JSM_DEMO\HIS0364\WINDOW\L3_TB3B_MNFLD.EDF" -d "D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common" -l "D:\FastTools\VPInput\CentumTagsToFASTTOOLSitems.csv"
```

Use the output redirection to exclude the error messages: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Simplified code:

```
@Echo OFF

Set "FTGraphicConverter_ExecutablePath=D:\Build\Build_2.0.023\GrConv\FTGraphicConverter.exe"
Set "EDF_File=D:\Customer Data\JSM Prj\JSM_DEMO\HIS0364\WINDOW\L3_TB3B_MNFLD.EDF"
Set "CSV_File=D:\FastTools\VPInput\CentumTagsToFASTTOOLSitems.csv"
Set "Output_Dir=D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common"

Set "Input_Displays_Dir=D:\FastTools\FTOutput\common\Displays"
Set "Outut_Displays_Dir=C:\Users\Public\tls\wap\cfg\operatorInterfaces\DEPLOY\displays"

Start /B "" "%FTGraphicConverter_ExecutablePath%" -s "%EDF_File%" -d "%Output_Dir%" -l "%CSV_File%" 2>NUL

%FTGraphicConverter_ExecutablePath% -s "%EDF_File%" -d "%Output_Dir%" -l "%CSV_File%"

xcopy /y "%Input_Displays_Dir%\*" "%Outut_Displays_Dir%\"
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to launch process in /Background and only want to interact with the error message autmatically then:

```
Echo Y| Start process.exe
```

If process.exe sends at the end a error message with a user prompt asking a question for "Y" "N" key then we automatically are sending the "Y" key so, if error at the end the execution will not stop.

Comment: "Echo Y| " will only work on some programs.   It's wise to make that clear.